# Angular Universal SSR CSS animation transform Error

Tags: css, angular, transform, universal

I have added Angular universal to my app and followed the guide on https://angular.io/guide/universal
It was realy simple, I'm just struggling with this Error:

ERROR Error: Unable to build the animation due to the following errors: The provided animation property "transform" is not a supported CSS property for animations
The provided animation property "transform" is not a supported CSS property for animations

The reason for this is a simple Button with a keyframe animation which uses transform: rotate(0deg);
The button is round and rolls from the right to the left side after loading.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue? I'm sure that transform is quite a valid CSS property for animations.

**Edit**:
I use the transform Property inside of a components scss file. The content is static and the component shows a whole site. The css code is this:

```
  .roll-in {  animation: 2s linear 0s 1 animation;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    left: 110%;
  }

  10% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    left: 110%;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-720deg);
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

After running the app with serve:ssr the element has no animation attribute.

Comment: Kindly post some code from what you have tried so far

Comment: I'm not sure which kind of code i should provide. I think the error is because of some server settings, but i have default values everywhere

Comment: Where are you using the `transform` property?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: Check `isPlatformBrowser()`, and then load the components which have animations.

Comment: ok, but i want to add more animations like scroll effect. They will not be available this way. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Add animations as much as you want, but load those components only in browser platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it happens when the animation starts on server side rendering itself. Since this is **SSR**, there is no meaning of loading the animations on server version.

Load the animations only in `Browser platform` version. So, animations will start only after the page rendered in browser view. For example,

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-animated-component',
  templateUrl: './my-animated-component.html'
})
export class MyAnimatedComponent{
  isBrowser: boolean;

  constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }
}
```

**In markup**

```
 <div *ngIf="isBrowser">
    <my-animated-component></my-animated-component>
 </div>
```

It's recommended to use Angular native animations rather than CSS animations. A working example is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animate-keyframes

Comment: thank you! Now I don't get an Error message any more but my button still has no animation attribute. If i start the app with ng serve the animation is there

Comment: Means, button presents but without animation?

Comment: Using angular native animations OR CSS animations? For keyframes, it's better to use angular native animation support https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animate-keyframes

Comment: Yeah, the button is present but without animation. The animation attribute is missing. I'm using CSS animation with keyframes. I will checkout your link

Comment: @keschra I have edited the answer to recommend angular native animations. Can you please mark it as `accepted` if it makes sense? So it will be helpful for others whoever working on Animations + SSR.